# pydantic - copy object fields to another, while excluding several fields

Tags: python, pydantic

i have a pydantic class:

```
class SomeData(BaseModel):
    id: int
    x: str
    y: str
    z: str
```

and lets say i have two object of this class, obj1, obj2.

is there any simple way, i can copy obj2, into obj1, while ignoring a subset of fields? for example copy all SomeData fields, except [id,z]

Answer (score 3):

Check out `model.copy(...)` ([docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#modelcopy)) and `model.dict(...)` ([docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict)) - particularly the `update: dict` and `exclude: set[str]` arguments.

Given two instances(obj1 and obj2) of SomeData, update the obj1 variable with values from obj2 excluding some fields:

```py
obj1 = SomeData(id=1, x='x', y='y', z='z')
obj2 = SomeData(id=2, x='x2', y='y2', z='z2')

obj1 = obj1.copy(update=obj2.dict(exclude={"id", "z"}))
# obj1 -> SomeData(id=1, x='x2', y='y2', z='z')
```

Note that this creates a new copy rather than mutate the original.

---

To *create* obj2 from obj1 excluding fields, you can directly use `.copy(exclude=...)`:

```py
obj1 = SomeData(id=1, x='x', y='y', z='z')

obj2 = obj1.copy(exclude={"id", "z"})
# obj2 -> SomeData(x='x', y='y')
```

Comment: Not sure, but from the way the question is phrased, it sounds like both objects are already initialized and OP wants certain fields of one overwritten by the contents of those fields in the other.

Comment: ah good catch. Updated my answer w/ a slightly tweaked version for that with a small note differentiating ours

Comment: in pydantic 2.x, `model.copy(...)` and `model.dump()` are deprecated.  To update the values, just replace `model.copy(...)`  by `model.model_copy(...)` and `model.dict(...)` by `model.model_dump(...)`

Comment: To exclude fields, you need to use `model_validation()`, but this raises an error for the answer model because "id" and "z" are required fields. I think this makes sense; it's unexpected to have a copy (with the same model type) without a required field. This is what .copy() does.

Answer (score 1):

in pydantic 2.x, use `model.model_copy(...)` ([docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#modelcopy)) and `model.model_dump(...)` ([docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict))

Given two instances(obj1 and obj2) of SomeData, update the obj1 variable with values from obj2 excluding some fields:

```py
obj1 = SomeData(id=1, x='x', y='y', z='z')
obj2 = SomeData(id=2, x='x2', y='y2', z='z2')

obj1 = obj1.model_copy(update=obj2.model_dump(exclude={"id", "z"}))
# obj1 -> SomeData(id=1, x='x2', y='y2', z='z')
```

Note that this creates a new copy rather than mutate the original.

---

To create obj2 from obj1 excluding fields, you need to use `model.model_validate()` ([docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.BaseModel.model_validate)), but note that this will raise `ValidationError` if you exclude a required field

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class SomeData(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[int] # -> set as optional, then we can create a copy excluding it
    x: str
    y: str
    z: str

obj1 = SomeData(id=1, x='x', y='y', z='z')
obj2 = obj1.model_validate(obj1.model_dump(exclude="id"))
# obj2 -> SomeData(id=None x='x' y='y' z='z2')
```

this will raise error

```py
# raise error, because 'x' is a required field.
obj2 = obj1.model_validate(obj1.model_dump(exclude="x"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If both `obj1` and `obj2` are already initialized and you want to overwrite certain fields of `obj1` with values from those fields on `obj2`, you would need to implement that yourself.

Something like this would work:

```py
from collections.abc import Container, Iterable
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel


class SomeData(BaseModel):
    id: int
    x: str
    y: str
    z: str

    def update(
        self,
        other: Iterable[tuple[str, Any]],
        exclude: Container[str] = (),
    ) -> None:
        for field_name, value in other:
            if field_name not in exclude:
                setattr(self, field_name, value)


obj1 = SomeData(id=1, x="a", y="b", z="c")
obj2 = SomeData(id=2, x="foo", y="bar", z="baz")

obj1.update(obj2, exclude={"id", "z"})
print(obj1)
```

Output: `id=1 x='foo' y='bar' z='c'`